# Query optimization or buffering

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I have this query on an iOS app:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT
    m.`id`, m.`no`, m.`name`, m.`image`, m.`stock`,
    mp.`unit_price_from`, mp.`unit_list_price_from`, mp.`unit_price`, mp.`unit_list_price`,
    (SELECT COUNT(`color_no`) FROM `variants` WHERE `model_no` = m.`no`) AS `variants_count`,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `color_no`) FROM `variants` WHERE `model_no` = m.`no`) AS `styles_count`
FROM `models` m
LEFT JOIN `model_prices` mp ON mp.`model_id` = m.`id`
WHERE
    `noos` = 2 OR `noos` = 1
```

On the simulator on my MacBook this just takes between `124ms` and `144ms`. I tried different INDEXES on model_no, color_no and the combined variations of them but they didn't result in faster queries. On an iPad 3 it becomes more tedious slowing down the query to `640ms`. This gives a small hiccup in the feel of the app which I really am trying to get rid of.

The `models` table already has an INDEX on the `noos` field too.

The `variants` table contains 12677 records.

The `model_prices` table contains 2792 records.

The `models` table contains 2792 records.

I was wondering if there is some way of reforming the COUNT subqueries to get faster results in SQLite. I only like to use some kind of manual caching as a last resort, but wanted to see first if some of you might see some optimization possibilities here.

Here's the EXPLAIN result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT m.`id`, m.`no`, m.`name`, m.`image`, m.`stock`,
       mp.`unit_price_from`, mp.`unit_list_price_from`, mp.`unit_price`, mp.`unit_list_price`,
       (SELECT COUNT(`color_no`) FROM `variants` WHERE `model_no` = m.`no`) AS `variants_count`,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `color_no`) FROM `variants` WHERE `model_no` = m.`no`) AS `styles_count`
FROM `models` m LEFT JOIN
     `model_prices` mp
      ON mp.`model_id` = m.`id`
WHERE m.`noos` IN (1, 2);
```

The best indexes should be:  `models(noos, id)`, `model_prices(model_id)`, and `variants(model_no, color_no)`.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't give me results under 120ms :(. I even tried over-INDEXing too by adding separate INDEXes on the `id`, `noos`, `color_no` and `model_no` fields. Is SQLite having the same quirks as MySQL where the query reformatter screws up by choosing different plans?

Comment: @Allendar . . . You do not want to overindex.  You want the composite (multiple-column) indexes mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I know Gordon, I was just stating the fact as a test. I reverted the INDEXes afterwards. Sadly none of the INDEX combinations improve the execution time.

Comment: @Allendar . . . You should simplify the query by removing the correlated subqueries and time it.  Then add back in a bit of complexity step-by-step and try to optimize the query as you go.